# Laravel 5 Joining Tables and Calculating Fields

Tags: laravel-5

I have 2 tables which have been joined.

**Table :** affiliate
**Fields** : company,affid
+---------------------------+
|company|affid            |
|Test1         | t1              |
|Test1         | t2              |

**Table** : applicant
**Fields** : affid,commission

+---------------------------+
|affid         |commission |
|t1               | 25              |
|t2               | 30              |

Each company has for example 2 affid's.

**So company name :** Test1
**Has affid :** t1,t2

What i am trying to do is pull a table that shows the company name and its total commission.

+---------------------------+
|company|commission|
|Test1         | 55              |

This is what i have , what changes do i need to make ?

```
        $data = DB::table('applicant')
         ->join('affiliate','applicant.affid','=','affiliate.affid')
            ->select(DB::raw('company,SUM(commission) as commission,'))
            ->groupBy('company')
            ->get();
```

Comment: As far as I know the only way this is achievable is with Raw expressions... Just like you did. You could however use ->selectRaw instead of instantiate DB::raw again...